# Analytic Isomorphism from open region to upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

How do we go about finding an analytic isomorphism from the open region between $|z|=1$ and $|z-\frac 12|=\frac 12$ to the upper half plane $\text{Im}\ z>0$.

What I know about analytic isomorphisms is just the definition: an analytic isomorphism $f:U\to V$ (where $U$ and $V$ are open sets) is an analytic function such that there exists another analytic function $g:V\to U$, satisfying $f\circ g=id_V$ and $g\circ f=id_U$.

Do we need the theory of Mobius Transformations for this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that the map $f(z) = \frac{-1}{1+z}$ maps the vertical strip $\lbrace z$ $|$ $0 < \text{Re}(z) < 1 \rbrace$ onto your domain in question, and so the inverse will map your domain onto the strip.

Now, mapping a strip onto the upper half-plane can be done with an exponential function $e^{\pi i z}$ if you choose the correct strip (hint: You already have the correct strip).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Which topic of complex analysis should I read up to learn more of this?

Comment: These are a standard sort of problem for preliminary exams; most books have a chapter on this sort of problem, but it's not really considered a "topic" in its own right.  Usually you learn (memorize) the geometric properties of the Mobius transformations, exponential/log, power functions, Cayley Transform and Joukowski Transform, and then some special cases like the intersection of two discs.  Compositions of these maps, with shifts, rotations and dilations give you a big class of conformally equivalent domains.  Then later you might prove some things regarding annuli and related domains.

Comment: Just to check, do you mean $f(z)=\frac{-2}{1+z}+1$?